# Android 4/ICS Context menu not showing up

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've looked at the other threads on this topic, and none of them have helped. I'm using an appropriate minSdkVersion, my menu xml appears setup correctly, my Manifest is calling Them.Holo.Light, and all of the other "typically overlooked" problems (that I'm aware of from other threads, anyway).

I'm using Eclipse with the latest SDK and following the basic tutorial from the Android dev wiki. Eclipse isn't showing any errors.

As you'll see, I'm referencing main.xml and main_activity.xml. main.xml is showing the default view when the app loads, which is a simple header bar and a picture of two ponies. The idea is that the user can use the context menu to swap between the pony picture and one of Lionel Richie (hey, it's a test app).

I've tried running it on the emulator, as well as my Xoom tablet and a phone, with no luck.

Code:

```
/***** Contents of testIceCreamS Manifest *****/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.icecreams"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TestIceCreamSActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


/***** Contents of TestIceCreamSActivity.java *****/

package test.icecreams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import test.icecreams.R;

public class TestIceCreamSActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}

/***** Contents of ActionBarUsage.java *****/

import test.icecreams.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
public class ActionBarUsage extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    LinearLayout bkgr = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.buttonone:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ponies);
            return true;
    case R.id.buttontwo:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
            return true;
    case R.id.buttonthree:
            bkgr.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundwhite);
            return true;
    case R.id.buttonfour:
            bkgr.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);
            return true;
    case R.id.buttonfive:
            //The alert code goes here!
            return true;
    default :
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}

/***** Contents of main_activity.xml: *****/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/buttonone"
    android:title="@string/showimage1"
    android:icon="@drawable/helloicon"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/buttontwo"
          android:title="@string/showimage2" 
          android:icon="@drawable/poniesicon" 
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/buttonthree" 
          android:title="@string/showwhite" 
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/buttonfour" 
          android:title="@string/showblack" 
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/buttonfive"
          android:title="@string/showalert" 
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>


/***** Contents of main.xml: *****/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hellotext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd"
    android:src="@drawable/ponies" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also have the content for strings.xml, but I figured it was probably the least important of all of these.

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 for ponies and Lionel Ritchie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I understand that you want to create an application running on ICS with the layout *main.xml* and a contextual menu like *main_activity.xml*. You do not have to create two activities, only the main one which will be launched at application will be started.

Please try to make all in one Activity in the same file TestIceCreamSActivity.java :

```
package test.icecreams;

import test.icecreams.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TestIceCreamSActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        LinearLayout bkgr = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.buttonone:
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ponies);
                return true;
        case R.id.buttontwo:
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
                return true;
        case R.id.buttonthree:
                bkgr.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundwhite);
                return true;
        case R.id.buttonfour:
                bkgr.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);
                return true;
        case R.id.buttonfive:
                //The alert code goes here!
                return true;
        default :
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Please also change your target SDK version to level 14 (ICS 4.0 -> 4.0.2) or 15 (4.0.3) in your manifest :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
          android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```